# frequency of onSensorChanged() is wierd(too fast)?

Tags: java, android, android-sensors

When I use `onSensorChanged()` to test my cellphone's accelerometer, finding that it responses to fast. Almost every 1~3ms `onSensorChanged()` will be activated. I search for some other cellphone's information feeling that it is kind of weird, so I doubt that my code might be wrong. Here is part of my code:

```
   public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent se_a) { /* 取得x,y,z加速度值 */
    xa = se_a.values[0];
    ya = se_a.values[1];
    za = se_a.values[2];

    final String timeStamp_a = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmssSSS",
             Locale.UK).format(new Date());

    String tmp_a = "0 " + timeStamp_a + " " + String.valueOf(xa)
    + " " + String.valueOf(ya) + " " + String.valueOf(za) + "\n";
```

And part of result is like:

```
0 160106203 9.5385 -0.6895301 1.1109096
0 160106204 9.500193 -0.5746084 1.1109096
0 160106206 9.576807 -0.5746084 1.1875241
0 160106207 9.461885 -0.6895301 1.3024458
```

My cellphone is LG G2. I set the accelerometer to `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`. But using some app on google play to test my accelerometer, it shows that in `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` the frequency is 120Hz, so it is very weird to find that `onSensorChanged()` response so fast(1~3ms). Where is my code can be wrong? Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the update rate is to fast using `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` you can set another flag which fit your needs.

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-monitor) for the different rates you can use:

> The default data delay (SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) is suitable for
>   monitoring typical screen orientation changes and uses a delay of
>   **200,000 microseconds**. You can specify other data delays, such as SENSOR_DELAY_GAME (**20,000 microsecond** delay), SENSOR_DELAY_UI
>   (**60,000 microsecond** delay), or SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST (**0
>   microsecond**!!!! delay). As of Android 3.0 (API Level 11) you can
>   also specify the delay as an absolute value (in microseconds).

Edit: Have a look at this method [SensorManager.registerListener(SensorEventListener, Sensor, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29) where you can specify your delay in ms if no flag supports your needs. This is available since API 9. If you want a specific frequenzy provide it as a parameter.

Comment: Actually, I prefer time delay as small as possible. But I want to know why this frequency is different from testing in this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cochibo.accfreq&hl=zh_TW 
I use this app and find that SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST is 120Hz. And I also find other people's testing on Internet:
http://ilessendata.blogspot.tw/2012/11/android-accelerometer-sampling-rates.html 
http://markmail.org/message/bs5xj2s56q4j4zhi 
The fastest frequency is also around 100Hz. Because I need this data in my research(deblurring), I have to make sure that they are senses correctly.

Comment: OK, I know that. Thanks for your response!!